# Changing a box colour and text colour on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following code which is for a styled subscribe button and I've been trying to get it so that on hover the background colour of the whole box changes and also the colour of the text 'Subscribe' to change colour as well. At the moment the code I have below changes the background colour but only changes the colour of the text if i hover directly on it. I want to be able to hover anywhere on the box and the two elements change colour together... Any one able to point out where I'm going wrong?

HTML:

```
<h3 class="subscribeHeader">
   <a href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
</h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3.subscribeHeader {
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #373737;
}

h3.subscribeHeader a:hover {
  color: #fafaf9;
}

h3.subscribeHeader:hover {
  background-color: #373737;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS can be over ridden.

**[js fiddle](http://jsbin.com/bacokedeyoje/1/)**

```
h3.subscribeHeader {
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #373737;
}

h3.subscribeHeader a:hover {
  color: #fafaf9;
}

h3.subscribeHeader:hover {
  background-color: #373737;
}

h3.subscribeHeader:hover a{
  color: #fafaf9;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this code    [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Blqni)

```
<a class='subscribeHeader' href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>


a {
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #373737;
  display:block;
}


a.subscribeHeader:hover {
  background-color: #373737;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Similarly I have another button elsewhere in my site which has the same stylings but I'm using Perch on this particular button and I'm applying the same code from this answer to that button and it isn't having the same outcome, any ideas? Below is my code -

Comment: HTML: <div class="buyHeader"><perch:input class="buttonStyling submit" type="submit" name="add" value="Buy Now" /></div>

Comment: CSS: .buyHeader {
 padding-top: 0.7em;
 padding-bottom: 0.7em;
 width: 35%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid #373737;
    }

    .buttonStyling {
 font-family: "futura-pt", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 color: #373737;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 background: none;
 border: none;
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
h3.subscribeHeader:hover > a {
  background-color: #373737;
  color: #fafaf9;
}
```

Can you please try this? The `>` means that it will affect an element right inside that box, so this should work. You can try `+` instead of `>` or just simply `h3.subscribeHeader:hover a`

Answer (score 1):

simplay add following css

```
h3.subscribeHeader:hover a {
  color: red;
```

}

this will call child element 'a' when hover over h3

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the text color when you hover the `h3` not the `a` so basically this should to the trick.

```
h3.subscribeHeader:hover {
  background-color: #373737;
  color: #fafaf9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your child elements and the image are sharing the same class:

```
    <div class="myclass"
<div class="myimageclass"</>
<div class="childelements"</>
</div>
```

Then you will have a problem.
Make sure the child elements and your image background are in two different classes,then style as desired like this:

```
      .img-back {
       background: #394557 url(images/space.jpg) ;
        background: #394557 url(images/space.jpg),linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531);/*login Page Background */
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
       opacity: 0.25;

.mychildelemts {
    width: 375px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="img-back"
    <div class="myimageclass"<div/>
    </div>
<div class="childelements"
<p> my children</p>
<div/>
</div>
```